# How to match strings with regex pattern like [aaa-bbb.com] in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have file which have domain name inside "[" "]" brackets. I want to check whether a particular domain name is present or not.

```
sub main
{
my $file = '/home/deeps/sample.txt';
open(FH, $file) or die("File not found");

my $host = "deeps-cet.helll.com";
my match_patt = "\[$host\]";
while (my $String = <FH>)
{
if($String =~ $match_patt)
   {
      print "match";
   }
}
close(FH);
}

main();
```

The above code throws error - Invalid [] range "s-c" in regex. help to resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bellow is corrected code, if you plan to use a variable for regular expression for this purpose available `my $regex = qr/..../`, and when you do match you should use construction `$variable =~ /$regex/;`

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $fname = shift || '/home/deeps/sample.txt';
my $host  = shift || 'deeps-cet.helll.com';

search($fname,$host);

sub search {
    my $fname = shift;
    my $host  = shift;
    my $regex = qr/\[$host\]/;
    
    open my $fh, '<', $fname
        or die "Can't open $fname";

    /$regex/ && say "match" while <$fh>;
    
    close $fh;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [quotemeta](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) to escape ASCII non-"word" characters, that could have a special meaning in the regex

```
my $match_patt = quotemeta "[$host]";
```

Or use `\Q` escape right in the regex, implemented using `quotemeta`. See docs.

What happens in your code is that the well-meant escape of the bracket, `\[`, is evaluated already under the double quotes when you form the pattern, so after `"\[$host\]"` is assigned to `$match_patt` then that variable ends up with the string `[deeps-cet.helll.com]`. These `[]` are treated as the range operator in the regex and fail because of the "backwards" `s-c` range.<sup>†</sup>

This can be seen with the pattern built using non-interpolating single quotes for `\[`

```
my $match_patt = '\[' . $host . '\]';
```

which now works.  But of course it is in principle better to use `quotemeta`.

---

<sup>†</sup> This is really lucky -- if the range were valid, like `ac-sb.etc`, then this would be a legitimate pattern inside `[]` which would silently do completely wrong things.